# Train voice recognition

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I have built a voice recognition system in C# and I’m using the Microsoft Speech Platform 11.0 (Swedish language packs). I use a wav file as an input for the SpeechRecognitionEngine.

The problem is that some of the words (40%) are not recognized at all.

I would like to record some commands (a limited number of Swedish words and/or numbers) to a sound file and import them so that the SpeechRecognitionEngine could be able to understand them.

For example:

Record when an user says the word: “Katt” (Swedish word for cat) and then be able to tell the RecognitionEngine that this means “Katt”.

Is this possible or are there better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible. Create a lookup entry file for your words and write soundex in c# and load the lookup grammar. It will display whichever the word you pronounced but it should be in the lookup.

Comment: Do you have some kind of example?